# The tangent space at a point of two-dimensional torus

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Consider the hyperbolic toral automorphism $A : T^2 \to T^2$
$$A (x, y) = (2x + y, x + y) \; \text{mod} \; 1.$$
Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold.

Can someone explain me who is the tangent space $T_x M$, for every $x \in T^2$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm also struggling with this.. Did you figure it out?